# PHP function to check that two arrays are the same while ignoring the values of specified keys

Tags: php, arrays, phpunit

I need a PHP function that can assert that two arrays are the same while ignoring the values of a specified set of keys (only the value, the keys must match).

In practice, the arrays must have the same structure, but some values can be ignored.

For example, considering the following two arrays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [title] => Book1 Title
            [creationDate] => 2013-01-13 17:01:07
            [pageCount] => 0
        )
)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Book1 Title
            [creationDate] => 2013-01-13 17:01:07
            [pageCount] => 0
        )
)
```

they are the same if we ignore the value of the key `id`.

I also want to consider the possibility of nested arrays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [title] => Book1 Title
            [creationDate] => 2013-01-13 17:01:07
            [pageCount] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [title] => Book2 Title
            [creationDate] => 2013-01-13 18:01:07
            [pageCount] => 0
        )
)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => Book1 Title
            [creationDate] => 2013-01-13 17:01:07
            [pageCount] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => Book2 Title
            [creationDate] => 2013-01-13 18:01:07
            [pageCount] => 0
        )
)
```

Since I need it for testing, I have come up with the following class that extends [PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html) and uses its assert functions:

```php
class MyTestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public static function assertArraysSame($expected, $actual, array $ignoreKeys = array())
    {
        self::doAssertArraysSame($expected, $actual, $ignoreKeys, 1);
    }

    private static function doAssertArraysSame($expected, $actual, array $ignoreKeys = array(), $depth, $maxDepth = 256)
    {
        self::assertNotEquals($depth, $maxDepth);
        $depth++;

        foreach ($expected as $key => $exp) {
            // check they both have this key
            self::assertArrayHasKey($key, $actual);

            // check nested arrays 
            if (is_array($exp))
                self::doAssertArraysSame($exp, $actual[$key], $ignoreKeys, $depth);

            // check they have the same value unless the key is in the to-ignore list
            else if (array_search($key, $ignoreKeys) === false)
                self::assertSame($exp, $actual[$key]);

            // remove the current elements
            unset($expected[$key]);
            unset($actual[$key]);
        }

        // check that the two arrays are both empty now, which means they had the same lenght
        self::assertEmpty($expected);
        self::assertEmpty($actual);
    }
}
```

`doAssertArraysSame` iterates through one of the arrays and asserts recursively that the two arrays have the same keys. It also checks that they have the same values unless the current key is in the list of the keys to ignore.

To make sure the two arrays have exactly the same number of elements, each element is removed during the iteration and, at the end of the loop, the function checks that both arrays are empty.

Usage:

```php
class MyTest extends MyTestCase
{
    public function test_Books()
    {
        $a1 = array('id' => 1, 'title' => 'the title');
        $a2 = array('id' => 2, 'title' => 'the title');

        self::assertArraysSame($a1, $a2, array('id'));
    }
}
```

My question is: is there a better or simpler way to accomplish this task, maybe using some already available PHP/PHPUnit functions?

EDIT: please bear in mind I *don't* necessarily want a solution for PHPUnit, if there was a plain PHP function that can do this, I can use it in my tests.

Comment: How about [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)? If it returns empty array means that arrays where the same.

Comment: @PLB yes, that could be of help, but `array_diff` only checks one dimension of a n-dimensional array, which means I would have to use it in a recursive loop anyway if I want to support nested arrays. Also, in my case, if the resulting array from `array_diff` is not empty, I would have to check whether the keys of that array are in the to-ignore list.

Comment: Are you actually writing a test? Or do you need this in code? I mean, your question implies you 'just' need the function, but then you shouldn't be using the testcase/assert class and functions. DId you check the comments on the array_diff manual page? A multidimensional example is in there somewhere.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: @Nanne I need it for testing, but I think this is irrelevant. If there was a good generic function that can do that out-of-the-box, I could use that in my TestCase class, that's why I asked for a function. This question is not necessarily tied to PHPUnit. Regarding `array_diff`, please see my previous comment. All the multidimensional solutions proposed in the manual page are awkward, inefficient or just for 2-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @testing: I agree, I meant it the other way around: If you are _not_ testing, it would be weird to use the classes you are using :). In the end, comparing multi-mentional arrays will need some form of depth one way or another. I'm not sure if you can get more efficient. Bottom line is you need to test all key/value pairs of your (nested) array. I'm not sure if you can un-awkward that.

Comment: Does it have to be recursive?

Comment: @feeela not necessarily, but it is likely it will be since I need to support multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a better solution than what you're already using, but I've used a similar class before when I had this exact need. It is able to give you a simple true or false response and isn't coupled to a testing framework, which may or may not be a good thing for you.

```
class RecursiveArrayCompare
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $ignoredKeys;

    /**
     *
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->ignoredKeys = array();
    }

    /**
     * @param array $ignoredKeys
     * @return RecursiveArrayCompare
     */
    public function setIgnoredKeys(array $ignoredKeys)
    {
        $this->ignoredKeys = $ignoredKeys;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $a
     * @param array $b
     * @return bool
     */
    public function compare(array $a, array $b)
    {
        foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
            if (in_array($key, $this->ignoredKeys)) {
                continue;
            }

            if (!array_key_exists($key, $b)) {
                return false;
            }

            if (is_array($value) && !empty($value)) {
                if (!is_array($b[$key])) {
                    return false;
                }

                if (!$this->compare($value, $b[$key])) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                if ($value !== $b[$key]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            unset($b[$key]);
        }

        $diff = array_diff(array_keys($b), $this->ignoredKeys);

        return empty($diff);
    }
}
```

And some examples based on your provided array:

```
$arr1 = array(
    'id' => 0,
    'title' => 'Book1 title',
    'creationDate' => '2013-01-13 17:01:07',
    'pageCount' => 0
);

// only difference is value of ignored key
$arr2 = array(
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => 'Book1 title',
    'creationDate' => '2013-01-13 17:01:07',
    'pageCount' => 0
);

// has extra key
$arr3 = array(
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => 'Book1 title',
    'creationDate' => '2013-01-13 17:01:07',
    'pageCount' => 0,
    'extra_key' => 1
);

// has extra key, which is ignored
$arr4 = array(
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => 'Book1 title',
    'creationDate' => '2013-01-13 17:01:07',
    'pageCount' => 0,
    'ignored_key' => 1
);

// has different value
$arr5 = array(
    'id' => 2,
    'title' => 'Book2 title',
    'creationDate' => '2013-01-13 17:01:07',
    'pageCount' => 0
);

$comparer = new RecursiveArrayCompare();
$comparer->setIgnoredKeys(array('id', 'ignored_key'));

var_dump($comparer->compare($arr1, $arr2)); // true
var_dump($comparer->compare($arr1, $arr3)); // false
var_dump($comparer->compare($arr1, $arr4)); // true
var_dump($comparer->compare($arr1, $arr5)); // false
```

### EDIT

The benefit to using a separate class such as this is that it's straight forward to unit test this class as well to ensure it behaves as expected. You don't want to rely on tools for your tests if you can't guarantee that they're working properly.

Comment: I like it. In my case, I would only move `if (!array_key_exists($key, $b)) { return false; }` before `if (in_array($key, $this->ignoredKeys)) { continue; }` to ensure the two arrays have exactly the same keys - I want to ignore only the value of an element, not the key.

Comment: Ok fair enough. You probably also want to remove the `array_diff` part then and just return `empty($b)` instead as it sounds like you want additional keys to be a difference even if they're ignored.

Comment: exactly, `return empty($b);`

Comment: One more thing: `(in_array($key, $this->ignoredKeys, true))` to perform strict check on the key (otherwise a value of `0` can give false positive).

Comment: To add more details on my comment above: check out the first comment on the manual page of `in_array`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 0):

You could foreach the array elements

```
foreach ($array1 as $index => $subArray)
{
    $this->assertEquals($array1[$index]['title'], $array2[$index]['title');
    $this->assertEquals($array1[$index]['creationDate'], $array2[$index]['creationDate');
    $this->assertEquals($array1[$index]['pageCount'], $array2[$index]['pageCount');
}
```